# Display freezing on wakeup

Tags: drivers, gnome, display, suspend, freeze

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have Lenovo Thinkpad E14 with dualboot Windows 10/Ubuntu 22.04. When I launch Ubuntu, there are no problems. But when the PC "goes to sleep" or "suspends" and wakes up, the display freezes, and I'm guessing Gnome crashes. I have to hard reboot every time the PC wakes up and then the problem is resolved until it wakes up again.

Does anyone know maybe where to check? Some details below

Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2

Graphics card is Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

64-bit

Gnome version - 42.9

Windowing Wayland

Similar question on UbuntuForums - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486292

````
lsmod | grep "kms\|drm"
find /dev -group video
cat /proc/cmdline
find /etc/modprobe.d/
glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
drm_buddy              20480  1 i915
drm_display_helper    212992  1 i915
cec                    94208  2 drm_display_helper,i915
drm_kms_helper        249856  2 drm_display_helper,i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              20480  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   696320  19 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,drm_buddy,thinkpad_acpi,i915,ttm
/dev/media0
/dev/video1
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=abd799ce-46f4-4ab3-9ca2-ea86e01d5c05 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
/etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-modem.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf
/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel```
````